# Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS - Blank screen/no response on resumption from suspend

Tags: 16.04, suspend, crash

I am new to Ubuntu. Added it to my Dell Latitude a few months back. Have been working great till recently (around 2 weeks), when it started crashing on resumption from suspend.

Here are the steps:
1. Put Ubuntu on suspend either by clicking through for suspend or shutting the lid
2. Restart after suspend - shows a blank screen - no response at all. Not reading hard disk, however I can hear the fan on.
3. I am having to hard reboot. Sometimes when it comes back again, it throws error on display driver or is not able to connect to wifi. I have to restart it again to make it work properly.

When I look at my /var/log/kern.log, I see an unusually large number of entries. Since I am new to Ubuntu, not able to figure out much myself.

Here are some issues I noticed. Would appreciate some help:

```
Nov  3 15:11:26 my-laptop NetworkManager[817]: <info>  [1541283086.9811] device (eno1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Nov  3 15:11:26 my-laptop kernel: [   29.370511] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
Nov  3 15:11:27 my-laptop NetworkManager[817]: nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed
Nov  3 15:11:27 my-laptop NetworkManager[817]: <info>  [1541283087.1719] device (lo): link connected
Nov  3 15:11:27 my-laptop NetworkManager[817]: <info>  [1541283087.1725] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Nov  3 15:11:27 my-laptop kernel: [   29.560174] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
Nov  3 15:11:27 my-laptop NetworkManager[817]: <info>  [1541283087.2320] urfkill disappeared from the bus
Nov  3 15:11:27 my-laptop NetworkManager[817]: <info>  [1541283087.2340] ofono is now available
Nov  3 15:11:27 my-laptop NetworkManager[817]: <info>  [1541283087.2341] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
Nov  3 15:11:27 my-laptop NetworkManager[817]: <warn>  [1541283087.2348] failed to enumerate oFono devices: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
```